# Запрос на SQL Server

Tags: sql

Есть таблица X со столбцами Sum1,Sum2,Sum3,Sum4,Sum5,Sum6,Sum7   1,2,3,4,5,6,7 .Каким запросом определить,что число в колонке Sum7 имеет максимальное значение?

Comment: Относительно чего оно имеет максимальное значение? Относительно других колонок или относительно других строк в таблице по столбцу Sum7?

Comment: относительно других колонок

Answer (score 0):

Да простит меня маньяк из книжки Макконнелла, который увидит этот код:

```
SELECT IIF(sum7>sum1
           AND sum7>sum2
           AND sum7>sum3
           AND sum7 > sum4
           AND sum7 > sum5
           AND sum7 > sum6, 'yes', 'no') AS result
FROM r;
```

Это если вам нужно относительно одной строки таблицы, а не всех строк.

**Дополнение к вашему комментарию:**

```
SELECT
  (SELECT MAX(F)
   FROM (
         VALUES(sum1),(sum2),(sum3),(sum4), (sum5), (sum6), (sum7)) T(F)) MaxF
FROM table
```

Ссылка на [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/cbac3/2)

Comment: А если просто определить какой sum из них максимум?

Comment: @Liona обновил ответ

Comment: create table Оценивание(
id int primary key identity,
 этап varchar(50),
 ФИО int,
 Январь int,
 Февраль int,
 Март int,
 Апрель int,
 Май  int,
 Июнь int,
 Июль int,
 Август int,
 Сентябрь int,
 Октябрь int,
 Ноябрь  int,
 Декабрь int,
 foreign key(ФИО) references спортсмены(id));                              
  insert into Оценивание values 
('Спортивное совершенствование',1,8,8,6,9,8,9,10,9,7,9,7,9),
('Предварительная подготовка',2,7,8,10,9,8,9,10,9,6,9,7,8);

Comment: у меня таблица оценивание спортсменов нужно определить в каком месяце у него наилучший результат

Comment: SELECT
  (SELECT MAX(F)
   FROM (
         VALUES('Январь'),('февраль'),('март'),('апрель'), ('май'), ('июнь'), ('июль'),
   ('август'),('сентябрь'),('октябрь'),('ноябрь'),('декабрь')) T(F)) MaxF
FROM оценивание;

Comment: сделала как вы сказали но в итоге выводит просто 'январь'

Comment: @Liona названия колонок требуется вводить без кавычек, т.е просто VALUES(Январь), а также желательно поля таблицы именовать латиницей, а не кириллицей.

Comment: А как сделать что выводился и месяц с максимальным значением?

Comment: @Liona Вам нужна структура таблицы month year value и делать max(value) и выбирать из строки month

Comment: Но у меня там 26 спортсменов и если делать на каждый месяц (12*26 )получится 312 строк(

Comment: @Liona Такой объем данных, а тем более в год не является существенным и я не вижу смысла за это переживать и такая структура более правильная, чем-то что вы используете сейчас и на каждый год зачем-то создаете новую таблицу. Почитайте пожалуйста про "нормальные формы баз данных".

Comment: Да,я читала про нормальные формы просто хотела облегчить себе работу.Т.е так никак не возможно и месяц вывести?

Comment: @Liona Тогда вы должны понимать, что такой структурой вы усложняете себе работу, в том числе по написанию запросов. Количество данных не играет роли, ведь выборку нужных вы делаете с помощью запроса, а не вручную листаете таблицу. Какие-то хитрые способы с джойном системной таблицы с описанием структуры наверное и есть, но я к сожалению таким никогда не пользовался, т.к. это все таки неправильно.

Comment: @ Firepro Cпасибо большое

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56992/discussion-between-liona-and-firepro).

Answer (score -1):

> определить,что число в колонке Sum7 имеет максимальное значение

```
GREATEST(Sum1,Sum2,Sum3,Sum4,Sum5,Sum6) < Sum7
```

Или для нестрогого варианта

```
GREATEST(Sum1,Sum2,Sum3,Sum4,Sum5,Sum6,Sum7) = Sum7
```

Comment: Минусну за невнимание к используемому ПО и незнание того, что в Microsoft SQL Server отсутствует функция GREATEST

Comment: @Firepro Покажите пальцем в то место, где автор указал, что имеет дело с ***Microsoft*** SQL.

Comment: Очевидно, что название в вопросе SQL Server относится к базе данных Microsoft, потому что другой базы данных с таким названием на рынке нет и название является зарегистрированным товарным знаком, не факт что в РФ, но все же.

Comment: Нет ничего более ошибочного, чем апеллировать к "очевидности". SQL Server - это категория программного обеспечения. И если сказать, что SQL-серверы Oracle, Posgres или там Firebird - это ни разу не SQL Server, то на Вас могут странно посмотреть...

Comment: Вы ошибочно привязываете слово SQL Server к категории программного обеспечения, которая называется СУБД (RDBMS) или SQL Database, но не Server. Зайдите на сайт Oracle и увидите, что название продукта Oracle Database, а попробуйте набрать в поиске Oracle SQL Server, увидите статью как подключить Oracle к Microsoft SQL Server. Если этого недостаточно, зайдите по ссылке тэга 'sql-server' на данном сайте http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server, и узнаете, что SQL Server на этом ресурсе как общепринятое значение продукта от Microsoft.